# What is the best captcha service available for JSP forms apart from ReCaptcha?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I want to secure my form from spambots by using a captcha service. I have tried ReCaptcha but it generates really hard words. Is there any other captcha service available which I can use. I have tried JCaptcha but it is also not very good.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally haven't used this service, but you can try [OpenCaptcha](http://www.opencaptcha.com/)

There is also [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am glad.  Please share your feedback once you use any of these.  Thanks.